# How to control order of CompositeCommand

Tags: prism

Is there a way to control the order in which commands that are registered in a CompositeCommand get called?  Do they get call and executed in a sequential order?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/75206c591ce547d7e78787f1ba52cb97257052a5/Source/Prism/Commands/CompositeCommand.cs), registered commands execute one after another, in the order of registration. There's no test for this in the [fixture](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/d71d7e64545b1b57a025b56125fa55aab26890c9/Source/Prism.Tests/Mvvm/CompositeCommandFixture.cs), though, so I wouldn't rely too heavily on this behavior.

Comment: Feel free to add a test and send a PR :)

Comment: What is the best practice to have a command that needs two things to occur in order be processed?  Do I use two separate DelegateCommand's or one DelegateCommand and then use a eventaggregator to call the second method